# How to define step load on gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm a Performance QC engineer, so far i used Visual Studio Ultimate to run load test bug now I'm going to change to gatling. So I'm a newbie on gatling and scala.

I'm defining the simulation with step-load scenario here:

- Initial: 5 user
- Maximum user count: 100 users
- Step duration: 10 seconds
- Step user count: 5 users
- Duration: 10 minutes

Meaning: start with 5 users > after 10 seconds increase 5 users: repeat until maximum 100 user and run the test in 10 minutes.

I tried some code and other injects but the result is not as expected:

```
splitUsers(100)
into(rampUsers(5)
over(10 seconds))
separatedBy(10 minutes)
```

Could you please help me to simulate the step load on gatling?

Answer (score 0):

define the User injection part in setUp something like this

```
setUp(
    scn.inject(
      atOnceUsers(5),            //Initial: 5 user
      nothingFor(10 seconds),    //A pause to uniform the step load   
      splitUsers(100) into atOnceUsers(5) separatedBy(10 seconds) //max user,split time,number of user
    ).protocols(httpConf))
```

the duration you can define just by using during function over scenario. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific about the result not being as expected?

According to the documentation your situation should be:

`splitUsers(100) into(rampUsers(5) over(10 seconds)) separatedBy atOnceUsers(5)`

If test duration is the target then have a look at Throttling in the Gatling documentation.

Comment: This should be comment in question.